# Does pymongo replica set client connection support auto fail over?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I created the following mongo replica sets by using mongo cli:

```
> config = { _id:"repset", members:[{_id:0,host:"192.168.0.1:27017"},{_id:1,host:"192.168.0.2:27017"},{_id:2,host:"192.168.0.3:27017"}]}

> rs.initiate(config);
```

All the mongo servers run properly.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> servers = ["192.168.0.1:27017", "192.168.0.2:27017", "192.168.0.3:27017"]
>>> MongoClient(servers)
>>> xc = MongoClient()
>>> print xc
MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> print xc.database_names()
[u'test_repsets', u'local', u'admin', u'test']
```

After I kill the local mongodb server, it shows me connection timeout error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It seems there is no auto fail over, although I defined the mongodb servers. 
I am wondering if pymongo handles fail over automatically, or how this situation is handled properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of pymongo are you using?

Comment: pymongo==3.0.3  I think I made mistake here: xc = MongoClient() should be xc = MongoClient(servers). Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in Pymongo 3.x you may want to explicitly state what replica set you are connecting to. I know Pymongo 3.x switched up some of the ways it handles being given an array of servers. I got this off the [Pymongo API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/high_availability.html#id1) about connections to replicas and auto failover

Comment: This is not why OP got the error and doesn't answer the question. You should read OP comment.

Comment: The answer is yes that pymongo supports auto failover. However Im suggesting an alternate way to connect to his replica set that may alleviate the problem. Server array has changed behavior in Pymongo 3.x. However OP has found his problem due to a coding error that was missed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

MongoClient(servers)
Above line is not assigned to any variable. It should assign to variable (in your case you again created instance which causes error.)

Please add following line

```
>>> #MongoClient(servers)             # remove this line
>>> #xc = MongoClient()               # remove this line
>>> xc = MongoClient(servers)         # add this line
```